# np.where equivalent for multi-dimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume you have a numpy array as `array([[5],[1,2],[5,6,7],[5],[5]])`.
Is there a function, such as `np.where`, that can be used to return all row indices where `[5]` is the row value? For example, in the array above, the returned values should be `[0, 3, 4]` indicating the `[5]` row numbers.

Please note that each row in the array can differ in length.

Thanks folks, you all deserve best answer, but i gave the green mark to the first one :)

Comment: Are you sure you even want an array here? What are you doing that would best be solved by a 1-dimensional array of variable-length lists?

Comment: In the real problem, those `[5]`'s are `[?]` indicating missing data, which I want them removed from the dataset. One way is to initialize another array that takes the row indices where `[?]` is not present. The reason why the structure is erratic is because some samples correspond to more than one class. Sorry about the Machine learning jargon, but thats the only way i can think of for explaining the importance of such arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
[i[0] for i,v in np.ndenumerate(ar) if v == [5]]
=> [0, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you check `ndim` of your array you will see that it is actually not a multi-dimensional array, but a `1d` array of list objects.

You can use the following list comprehension to get the indices where 5 appears:

```
[i[0] for i,v in np.ndenumerate(a) if 5 in v]
#[0, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or the following list comprehension to get the indices where the list is exactly `[5]`:

```
[i[0] for i,v in np.ndenumerate(a) if v == [5]]
#[0, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the the list comprehension as here:

```
[i[0] for i,v in np.ndenumerate(a) if 5 in v]
#[0, 2, 3, 4]
```